# AWS managed airflow to Databricks SSL error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, databricks, mwaa

I am trying to use databricks inbuilt operator provided by airflow such as DatabricksSubmitRunOperator or DatabricksRunNowOperator but i am not able to use it, it gives below error:

Attempt 1 API Request to Databricks failed with reason: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='usdev.databaricks.xyz.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/jobs/run-now (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))

if i were to use custom python code then i can supply verify = False in requests module of python but since i am using this inbuilt operator i don't see any option to disable the ssl validation from airflow to databricks.

sample code being used:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import (
    DatabricksRunNowOperator,
)
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

"""
SUCCESS SCENARIO.
- It will run the job_id=14, that is already created in databricks.
- Basically, it will trigger what that job is supposed to do (that is, run a notebook)
"""


# Define params for Run Now Operator
notebook_params = {"Variable": 5}


with DAG(
    "databricks_dag_run_now",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2),
    },
) as dag:

    t0 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start'
    )

    opr_run_now = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
        task_id="run_now",
        databricks_conn_id="custom_databricks_conn",
        job_id=12345,
        notebook_params=notebook_params,
    )


    t0 >> opr_run_now
```

Answer (score 0):

From the host name I can suppose that you're using load balancer or something like proxy before actual Databricks workspace, and this load balancer/proxy uses the self-signed certificate (actual certificates of Datarbicks workspaces are signed with well-known CA certificate).

To solve your problem you need to extract a CA certificate that was used to sign certificate of your load balancer/proxy (`usdev.databaricks.xyz.com`), for example, using the code from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file) or using web browser, and add it to the certificate chain of `certifi` package that is used by `requests` package with something like this (shell script, certificate should be in the PEM format):

```sh
CERTIFI_HOME="$(python -m certifi 2>/dev/null)"
cat path_to_certificate_file >> $CERTIFI_HOME
```

Comment: Hey Alex! thanks for your answer, but as i said we have managed aws airflow, so I am not sure how we can run this command !! because in that instance we can not even do ssh as well.

Comment: ah, sorry - missed this part. I think that this will require an extension of Databricks Airflow operator to support tuning of SSL options, or something like this. I recommend to create an issue for Airflow